# Bloquear redimensión imagen html css

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

buenas

Estoy implementando un sitio web en el que quiero que al entrar a mi web la imagen principal no se redimensione, es decir, si entras desde un ordenador o desde un movil se vea la misma imagen. Aunque sea mas pequeña.

Incluyo fotos de como lo quiero: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y de como lo tengo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pondría algo de código pero no se si es culpa del css o del html.
Agradecería su ayuda

Comment: Utiliza pixeles para definir la altura y la anchura de la imagen, de esta manera siempre mediran lo mismo.

Comment: Deberías poner algo de código, si solo fuera una imagen con un ancho en porcentajes seria suficiente pero parece un slider y habría que ver como está construido

Answer (score 3):

Primero necesitas añadir la etiqueta `meta#viewport` para escalar la página en versión movil

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

Una vez lo tienes, mete la imagen en el background del div deseado con el siguiente css

```
background-image: url(../images/background2.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
```

Necesitas decir al navegador que no se repita y que quede centrada, Importante no le añadas

```
background-size: cover;
```

Dado que le indicas al navegador que quieres que ocupe el 100% del width

Answer (score 2):

Puedes agregar en un archivo css la "función" media screen

```
@media screen and (max-width: 980px)
{
//Este css solo se aplicara cuando el ancho de la pantalla
//sea maximo 980px
}
```

Con esto puedes editar tu magen en un ancho y alto que tu quieras.

Saludos y mucha suerte

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema no es la imagen en sí, es el componente, revisando el sitio "fcsimal" y la del diseño que quieres noté que son componentes distintos. Ahora, la imagen es el background de la sección y no un componente de la transición, adicional a esto, tendrías que ocultar el texto que se mueven en las transiciones o hacerlo ajustar a la imagen.
Mi recomendación, busca un componente "carrusel" o el que ya tienes y asigna ahí la imagen.

En rojo donde tienes la imagen, en verde el componente donde deberías tenerla.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]